# Q: How get two value in two dictionary with same keys in python

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value, enumerate

i'm trying my code. I'm confused..How to combine these 2 dictionaries so that the value of the results is like this?

```
1 A 18
5 B 14
3 C 15
7 D 20
```

for code

```
d= {'A': 1, 'B': 5, 'C': 3, 'D': 7}
e= {'A': 18, 'B': 14, 'C': 15, 'D': 20}
for k,v in d.items():
    print (v)
for i,(k, v) in enumerate(e.items()):
    print(i,k, v)
```

i don't understand. Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: a what does your code do, and how does it behave different than you expect? Or is important to detail direct vs expected behavior in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
d = {'A': 1, 'B': 5, 'C': 3, 'D': 7}
e = {'A': 18, 'B': 14, 'C': 15, 'D': 20}

for k in sorted(d.keys() & e.keys()):
    print(d[k], k, e[k])
```

The `&` ensures that we only use the keys present in *both* `d` and `e`.

Note that we need the `sorted` call to ensure that the `dict`s are indexed alphabetically in the situation where the `dict` keys aren't alphabetically inserted in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

```
d= {'A': 1, 'B': 5, 'C': 3, 'D': 7}

e= {'A': 18, 'B': 14, 'C': 15, 'D': 20}

for i in d.keys():

  print(d[i],i,e[i])
```

As the key in both dictionaries are same, so if you access one key you can easily access values from both the dictionaries and can print it in any order/format.

Answer (score 0):

```py
d= {'A': 1, 'B': 5, 'C': 3, 'D': 7}
e= {'A': 18, 'B': 14, 'C': 15, 'D': 20}

final_dictionary = {x: d.get(x, 0) + e.get(x, 0)
                    for x in set(d).union(e)}

print("final dictionary", str(final_dictionary))
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.